# StoreKit items getting purchased outside the app (redirected from my app to the App Store app)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have an app using the non-renewing subscription model. It works great when using in-app purchase test accounts. However, on Apple's production servers, sometimes the user gets taken away from my app to the app store for one reason or another (sometimes it's because of updated billing info, sometimes it's to answer security questions). This is after the payment has been added to the queue and in Apple's own payment flow. Once the user hits the alert view option to go into the app store, my transaction Observer gets a transaction with the `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed` state. That's fine. However, after the user updates their billing info or confirms their security question, they're asked (still outside the app) if they still want to purchase the in-app purchase. When that goes through, they are taken back to my app (which has closed itself), and nothing comes back from the transaction observer. The queue only gets updated with the purchased product when the list of products is retrieved. The observer registers for notifications before

So my questions are:

**How do I handle purchases made outside my app (in the app store app)?**

**If there are purchases made before the app opened (but not completed), at what point does the queue get updated?** I know that I should have the observer going at all times, but I want to avoid having the user purchase the item twice, not knowing they had already purchased it.

Answer (score 0):

Through some trial and error, I seemed to have solved my problem

It turns our that I wasn't initializing my transaction observer for `SKPaymentQueue` soon enough. It needs to be initialized and added as a transaction observer in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, and no later. As for when the transaction comes in, the `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions` method of your transaction observer will get called with a purchased transaction the next time your app is active. It's important to note that your app may or may not close once for one reason or another when you're taken to the App Store, and if it does end up closing, the method will get called the next time the app opens.